# Best way to remove an element in an XML using anti-xml

Tags: scala, anti-xml

What would be the best and/or simplest way to remove an element from a XML document using anti-xml?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
(xml \ "nodeToRemove").filter { _.name != "nodeToRemove"}.unselect.head
```

Any others?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this is better or not, but you could use the `drop` method, like so:

`(xml \\ 'nodeToRemove drop 1).unselect.head`

which assumes a single occurrence of `nodeToRemove`; you can drop all items in the resulting `Zipper` if there is more than one occurrence.

Also, as the `drop` complements, the `take` and `slice` methods remove anything that's not included in their ranges.